# Emscripten - surfData.colors32 is undefined, SDL_FillRect

Tags: javascript, c++, sdl, emscripten

I'm using Emscripten to try to get an open source game to run in a browser. It compiles fine, loads all of its files any everything, but when I run it it get the following exception:

```
exception thrown: TypeError: surfData.colors32 is undefined,_SDL_FillRect@file:///home/misson20000/dev/js/game.js:9702:9
__ZN9Surface5ClearEhhh@file:///home/misson20000/dev/js/game.js:112026:3
...
_main@file:///home/misson20000/dev/js/game.js:10525:11
asm._main@file:///home/misson20000/dev/js/game.js:170793:10
callMain@file:///home/misson20000/dev/js/game.js:173065:15
doRun@file:///home/misson20000/dev/js/game.js:173122:7
run/<@file:///home/misson20000/dev/js/game.js:173134:7
```

The code that is calling SDL_FillRect (a simple clear function) follows:

```
SDL_FillRect(fSurface, NULL, MapColor(r, g, b));
```

MapColor is defined as

```
return SDL_MapRGB(fSurface->format, r, g, b);
```

Digging around in the source code for a bit reveals that the surface in question is a screen surface.

How can I made surfData.colors32 *not* be undefined?

Answer (score 0):

The colors32 is used when you create SDL surface with SDL_HWPALETTE flag. To correctly use surface of this type you should call SDL_SetColors before SDL_FillRect. Take a look in src/library_sdl.js:

```
SDL_SetColors: function(surf, colors, firstColor, nColors) {
  var surfData = SDL.surfaces[surf];

  // we should create colors array
  // only once cause client code
  // often wants to change portion
  // of palette not all palette.
  if (!surfData.colors) {
   var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(256 * 4); // RGBA, A is unused, but faster this way
   surfData.colors = new Uint8Array(buffer);
   surfData.colors32 = new Uint32Array(buffer);
  }
  //...
}
```